# Stacky - A .NET client library (Full support for API v2.0)

Tags: library, api-v2, c#, .net, windows-phone

## Stacky - A .NET Client Library

### The same great library now supports the 2.0 API!

https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky

### Sample Code

```
IUrlClient urlClient = new UrlClient();
IProtocol protocol = new JsonProtocol();

var client = new StackyClient(version, apiKey, Sites.StackOverflow, urlClient, protocol);
var questions = client.GetQuestions();
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
}
```

**Silverlight and Windows Phone**

```
IUrlClient urlClient = new UrlClient();
IProtocol protocol = new JsonProtocol();

var client = new StackyClient(version, apiKey, Sites.StackOverflow, urlClient, protocol);
client.GetQuestions(questions =>
{
    foreach (var question in questions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
    }
});
```

You can view more detailed documentation in *[Getting Started](http://stacky.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started)*.

### About

[Stacky](http://stacky.codeplex.com) is a .NET client library for the Stack Apps API. It is a simple library and to supports a variety of platforms such as Silverlight and Windows Phone 7, .NET 4 and .NET 3.5.

#### License

MSPL

#### Download

http://stacky.codeplex.com

#### Source

[https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky](https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky/)

#### Platform

.NET (Windows, Windows Phone 7). Not tested on [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)).

### Contact

Luke Foust - Feel free to contact through [CodePlex site](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/lfoust)

### Code

.NET 4, .NET 3.5, C#, Silverlight 4, Windows Phone 7

Comment: How would one retrieve a tags FAQs? e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/forms/faq

Comment: @eth0 - I am not aware of an easy way to get tag FAQs in the current API. You can get questions by tag and you can get linked questions but I don't know of a way to link them together and sort them.

Comment: Is there any way to get a user's badges (the `/user/badges` route)?  See this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091513/how-to-get-badges-for-a-user-with-stacky#question

Comment: I didn't see a nuget package for version 2, and I built the 2.0 branch from source, it complains about "Sites.Stackoverflow doesn't contain a definition for "APiEndpoint" or "Description".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Sorry, I need to do some branch merging back into main. If you build the V2 branch it should build fine. And you are right, I haven't updated the nuget package to v2 yet.

Comment: Any consideration of porting this over to the WinRT or as a Portable Class Library?

Comment: @KronoS I have considered porting to WinRT but just don't have the time. If you are interested in tackling it let me know ;)

Comment: @lfoust lemme get through my first build of my app and then I'll see if I can dedicate some time to port this over.  If I decide to do so, I'll let you know.

Comment: Your bitbucket source code isn't complete.  Missing some sites in `sites.cs`.  Can I suggest that you either use the bitbucket or the codeplex as it's quite confusing which is the most up to date.

Comment: Also I'm working on a WinRT derivative of this.  When I'm done, I'll let you know so you can approve ;)

Comment: now that 4.5 not supported any longer, is there an update for 4.6 target

Comment: @FedRAMP There hasn't been any active development on this library for several years. You are welcome to contribute any changes you are interested in seeing: https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to let everybody know that I just made a new release of the library [here](http://stackoverflow.codeplex.com/releases/view/46411). This release includes tons of bug fixes as well as some **breaking changes** which shouldn't be a problem if you have been running off the trunk.

Also, by popular demand, I added a **.Net 3.5 version of the library** to this release. The hope here is to eventually have a mono version and possibly an Silverlight 3 version if there is any interest.

Please feel free to leave any feedback [on the codeplex site](http://stacky.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx) or submit any bugs [here](http://stacky.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Thanks for helping me make this great release!

Comment: Awesome library! I'm hoping to release an "alpha" of my first app based off your library in a few days :-)

Comment: May I suggest that you update the links in this post at least to reflect the libraries new CodePlex site http://stacky.codeplex.com/ as this might confuse new users (and defeats SEO btw. ;)

Answer (score 4):

With the way the API is currently set up (lots of caching the info page says) is it possible to update the information on a question you've already looked at? I have a list of questions but, as time goes on, the information changes (# of answers, votes, etc) and I would like to be able to update the questions with the new info.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. If you do: Question q = client.GetQuestion(12324); ...Then some time passes... and you do q = client.GetQuestion(12324); wouldn't that do the trick? Are you asking if there is a way to bypass the cache?

Comment: @lfoust Yeah, but I need it to work when not very much time passes. So yeah, is there a way to bypass the cache basically.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this super library!

I've used it for [my Overflow 7 app](https://stackapps.com/q/1942/7653). (See also [the Overflow 7 video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oErDi_YjKAA).)

I've put [a few detailed comments on your Stacky codeplex discussion site](http://stacky.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=242369). I hope they help.

Thanks again,
Stuart

Answer (score 2):

In the `StackyClient.GetQuestions` function, for the `tags` parameter, will you get questions with *any* of the tags in the array, or questions that have *all* of the tags in the array?

Also I don't see really any documentation except for the page with a few examples, which don't explain what exactly the parameters do and stuff. If anyone could link me to a thorough documentation or tell me where to find one it would be much appreciated.

Also, this is an excellent library, and very reliable. Good job OP.

Comment: Since the methods and parameters pretty much exactly mirror that of the actual stack exchange API, I decided to not repeat that work. You can view their awesome documentation here: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage. Let me know if you think there would be some value in making a comprehensive documentation for Stacky which is kept in sync with the official stack exchange API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Feature Request**

If you look at [my other question over here](https://stackapps.com/questions/589/finding-a-user-given-their-exact-display-name), I figured out that by specifying `min`&`max` I can get a basic "exact match" feature working for user name searches. The main problem is that StackOverflow.Net doesn't support string `min` and `max` parameters. I've added the following overloads to my own copy of UserMethods.cs:

```
public virtual IPagedList<User> GetUsers(string min, string max, UserSort sortBy = UserSort.Reputation, SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Descending, int? page = null, int? pageSize = null, string filter = null, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
{
    var response = MakeRequest<UserResponse>("users", null, new
    {
        key = apiKey,
        page = page ?? null,
        pagesize = pageSize ?? null,
        filter = filter,
        sort = sortBy.ToString().ToLower(),
        order = GetSortDirection(sortDirection),
        fromdate = fromDate.HasValue ? (long?)fromDate.Value.ToUnixTime() : null,
        todate = toDate.HasValue ? (long?)toDate.Value.ToUnixTime() : null,
        min = min ?? null,
        max = max ?? null
    });
    return new PagedList<User>(response.Users, response);
}

public virtual IPagedList<User> GetUsers(IEnumerable<int> userIds, string min, string max, UserSort sortBy = UserSort.Reputation, SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Descending, int? page = null, int? pageSize = null, string filter = null, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
{
    var response = MakeRequest<UserResponse>("users", new string[] { userIds.Vectorize() }, new
    {
        key = apiKey,
        page = page ?? null,
        pagesize = pageSize ?? null,
        filter = filter,
        sort = sortBy.ToString().ToLower(),
        order = GetSortDirection(sortDirection),
        fromdate = fromDate.HasValue ? (long?)fromDate.Value.ToUnixTime() : null,
        todate = toDate.HasValue ? (long?)toDate.Value.ToUnixTime() : null,
        min = min ?? null,
        max = max ?? null
    });
    return new PagedList<User>(response.Users, response);
}
```

Note in this overload, I had to make `min` and `max` *not* take default values (otherwise the overload resolution got confused if you didn't specify either of them). Not sure if that's the best way, but it works for me :)

Comment: I'll have to give some thought to this. I think I would prefer to just add a boolean matchExact (like you originally suggested in your question) to the method and then in the implementation I could translate that to using the min and max parameters. Exposing this min and max wierdness directly to the API consumers seems confusing to me.

Comment: @lfoust: Fair enough. I'd prefer the `exactMatch=true` way as well...

Comment: @lfoust and codeka - the min/max parameters are still incorrectly documented as dates when in fact they should be treated as a variant string that is contextually bound to sort. see http://stackapps.com/questions/671

Answer (score 1):

#### Feature Request

The *active questions queue* shows posts that have been edited. I like to watch that. But I can't get a List of **Answers** sorted by activity, only Questions. I am looking for something like this

```
var o = new PostOptions();
o.SortBy = Sort.Activity;                
o.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;                
o.FromDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10);
var list = client.GetPosts(o);
```