# Odd String Format Result from API Call

Tags: support, api, c#, getting-started

I'm just getting started messing around with the SO API. I haven't worked with JSON before, and I am getting a strange result from a basic call (No API Key).

```
WebClient stackClient = new WebClient();
string result = stackClient.DownloadString(@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats");
```

The result is:

> ‹í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"~ñoœ¤éGM›µEÓÓæ£Gé÷ðQšþbùAß¶U›•¿ÿ/ZçÔ¢Z¢É§Ÿ~ºs0ê´X/³es•×ùŒšìîÜ¸{¯ÛDÄîÃ½ýƒûûÝÓj±È—-Zì=Ø¹·ói¯—ËªÍ‡vwwöº_O²Ù…|ÿpÿþnþº‘î÷öïïÝ»ï¾µ£ûýWyýû/ŠåºÍ©ÙÎøÁ×H±›ìŽ?õî{@¼ž²Uñû_êŒ¾³T¦oÜ§íŒ>²¯ÐWu~Y˜ïvÇ;ãÝ½{ûãûŸ>8øÈ4ú%ò
>   ÿøþoœü’äÿNïþìÚ

I'm not sure what sort of formatting I'm missing, but this looks like I'm missing something obvious, it just isn't obvious to me.

Any thoughts?

Edited to add a bit of code to decompress the API data:

```
WebClient stackClient = new WebClient();
byte[] compressedData = stackClient.DownloadData(@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats");
int messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(compressedData, 0);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(compressedData,0,compressedData.Length))
        {
            byte[] decompressedData = new byte[messageLength];
            using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                gZip.Read(decompressedData, 0, decompressedData.Length);
            }

            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedData);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the GZipped stream of the response content. Use `DownloadData` instead of `DownloadString` and uncompress the stream before passing it to the JSON deserializer (or whatever you plan to use).

Alternatively, you can use the [StackOverflow.Net](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stackoverflow-net-client-library) library.

Comment: Thanks, you're a scholar and a gentlemen...StackOverflow.Net looks really nice.

Answer (score 4):

All responses from the API are compressed.  You can specify the compression scheme (gzip or deflate) in the `Accept-Encoding` header.  If you don't specify, one will be chosen for you.

We *used* to throw up an error when a non-compressed request was received, but a frustrating number of proxies don't pass `Accept-Encoding` through properly; so instead we silently patch up omissions now.