# Newest unaswered by tags

Tags: app, questions, c#, unanswered, wpf

### Screenshot

[image: Application screenshot]

### About

Often, when I was looking for questions to answer on StackOverflow, I would go through newest unanswered questions and look for those that had one of my favorite tags. The “my tags” tab is not very useful for me, because questions listed there are quite hard most of the time. So, I created this simple WPF app for myself and people with similar needs. You can copy & paste your favorite tags from SO, SF or SU and you won't see any of those boring Java questions anymore.

#### License

[Ms-PL](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html)

#### Download

[Download from github](http://github.com/downloads/svick/StackExchange-newest-unanswered-by-tags/Newest%20unanswered%20by%20tags%202010-06-28.rar)

#### Platform

Windows with .NET 4

### Contact

[Petr Onderka (svick)](http://github.com/svick)

### Code

Written in C#, uses [StackOverflow.Net](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stackoverflow-net-client-library).

[Available from the git repository at github](http://github.com/svick/StackExchange-newest-unanswered-by-tags).

Comment: C'mon, why do you have to make fun of Java?

Comment: Java is ugly. And slow.

Comment: @jinguy Just because I'm not interested in Java and so I don't want to see questions about Java.

Comment: I don't know if this was there last year? But now it's possible to add ignore-tags. Then they will not show in the list - anyways, just stumbled by and wanted to notify of the lessened relevance of this.