# Return URL of the non-API question URL

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I would find it very useful, if the API response for question (and answer etc.) contained a URL to the question page itself (preferably absolute).

E.g. the response for question 305 here would contain a field with the URL [Newest unaswered by tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/305/newest-unaswered-by-tags).

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the question id on the end of https://stackapps.com/questions/ to get what you want. So

[Newest unaswered by tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/305/)

is the same as

[Newest unaswered by tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/305/newest-unaswered-by-tags)

If you really want the full URL you may want to give a use case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first too, but the developer of StackOverflow.Net seems to disagree with that: http://stackoverflow.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=6214#ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_Content_CommentsRepeater_ctl00_PostedByLink

Comment: The Property is now public, but it has the APi, maybe you can use the timeline URL.