# should min/max for alpha-numeric cases be case-insensitive?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am having a hard time coming up with a use case in which case-sensitive min/max parameters make sense and several solid cases for a case-insensitive min/max.

Example:

With case insensitive min/max:

an exact match on /users could be accomplished with `min=john&max=john`

Currently, for this case, `min=john&max=JOHN` seems to work, but it is possible for other values to sneak in there requiring a client side post filter.

Discussed on [Finding a user given their (exact) display name](https://stackapps.com/questions/589) and  https://stackapps.com/questions/1041 and

Comment: Yeah, they really shouldn't be case sensitive.  Fixing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

Observe, as I filter out all the [Jons](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?min=jon&max=jon&sort=name), [Johns](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?min=john&max=john&sort=name), and [Jon Skeets](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?min=jon+skeet&max=jon+skeet&sort=name) in the system.