# StackFlair - **Defunct** Generate flair for your Stack Exchange associated accounts

Tags: app, obsolete, website, flair

Note:  This app, and the associated website have been offline since 2012.
The GitHub project may still be useful to you.

---

### Sample flair styles:

[image: rchern A]
[image: rchern B]
[image: rchern C]

### About

There have been several requests on Meta Stack Overflow for a way to get a combined flair similar to what is shown on Area 51. I took a "I want it, I'll make it" approach. Thus became *StackFlair*.

StackFlair generates a combined flair representing all of your associated Stack Exchange accounts.  StackFlair includes:

- Your gravatar from your top site (by reputation points)
- Your display name from your top site
- Your total reputation points
- The number of sites you are a moderator on
- The total number of gold badges
- The total number of silver badges
- The total number of bronze badges
- Favicons for your top six sites

<sub>Area 51 is currently excluded as the site is not included in the API.</sub>

The default output is HTML to support linking and titles for the elements contained in the flair. **You can also get image output.**

I provide a very simplistic UI for selecting a Stack Exchange site and inputting a user id. The generated content can also be linked to directly so that you can use the URL anywhere you can embed an image or pull dynamic HTML.

Several options are available: themes, excluding beta sites, using a single site or combined flair, HTML or image output. I am very open to more feature requests regarding customization options, theme, and layout.

Your StackFlair data is stored for 12 hours.

#### Website Usage

StackFlair homepage (Now dead): <strike>http://stackflair.com</strike>

Direct flair link (Now dead): <strike>http://stackflair.com/generate/{associationId}</strike>

When you visit the StackFlair homepage and enter in the details, you will be redirected to a direct flair link which you can use from then on.

#### Compatibility

StackFlair has been tested in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 7, and the mobile version of [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) (iPhone).

### Issue Reporting and Tracking

Please report any bugs, feature requests, and issues at [the *StackFlair* GitHub project](http://github.com/rchern/StackFlair).

I am happy to do even the smallest of requests, such as *My blog colors are <x>, can you use that in a theme for me?*

StackFlair is also listed on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/view_app.php?id=53)

#### License and Code

StackFlair is an ASP.NET website written in C#. The [Stacky](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library) library is used for API access.

The project is hosted at [github.com/rchern/StackFlair](http://github.com/rchern/StackFlair).

Comment: @jjnguy, feature requests go [here](http://github.com/rchern/StackFlair/issues/issue/2) :p  I excluded linked-meta sites as your rep there is dependent on the parent site.  Otherwise you could end up with 3 pairs rather than 6 sites.

Comment: Sorry to say, but StackFlair has been broken for a few weeks:  Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

etc...

Comment: still busted? or in the process of being fixed?

Comment: Any plans on fixing this?

Comment: "This domain may be for sale"

Comment: @Brock, that's as blunt as it gets, title and header changes duly noted!

Answer (score 8):

The site no more exists and so no more flair generation. I found **[se-flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair)** useful:

> See https://se-flair.2718.us/ for more complete instructions. Short version:
>
> - `https://se-flair.2718.us/[account-id].html` produces an HTML document suitable for iframe-embedding
> - `https://se-flair.2718.us/[account-id].js` produces JavaScript code that inserts the stylesheet link into the document head and writes the flair `div` into the document
> - `https://se-flair.2718.us/[account-id].png` produces a PNG image of the flair
>
> Note that your account-id is the numeric ID in the URL for your profile on [the main stackexchange.com website](http://stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 7):

Thee is now a wiki page on GitHub showing [usage examples](http://github.com/rchern/StackFlair/wiki/Usage).  I've committed the code and will be cleaning it up and commenting it soon.

The features I had planned from the beginning are now fully implemented.  Here's a list of features:

- Combined flair stats
- Single site support
- Html output
- Image output
- Exclude beta sites
- Better url support
- Themes

I'll be adding more themes, so if you've got some color schemes in mind, head over to the [GitHub site](http://github.com/rchern/StackFlair/issues).  Any feature suggestions (and bugs...I suppose) are welcome.  I've implemented my ideas, so let's hear yours.

somee.com will not be my host for much longer.  StackFlair.com is coming soon!

Comment: I don't like being a wiki page, but I suppose I sure am useful. :)

Comment: I'm only downvoting this so the other answer can float to the top. Thousands of upvotes for your previous work!

Answer (score 5):

Its really broken right now. I as @Basic mentioned auto-complete drop-down disappears after the first key press.

And also after submitting I too got same exception `System.Exception: Favicon file does not exist`, see image attached.

Please try to fix it as its really awesome idea.

[image]

Comment: I know this is months old, and I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but I found out you can get your stackflair from this website: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be broken right now...

When entering a username, the auto-complete drop-down with Gravatars disappears after the first key press.

When submitting the form, I get YSOD `System.Exception: Favicon file does not exist`

I think the idea is great but the UI could do with being a little more robust...

Comment: I get the same. At first, I thought it's because my name contains a unicode character, but then yours doesn't… It seems to work for some users and not others.

Comment: I know this is months old, and I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but I found out you can get your stackflair from this website: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair