# Mismatch between user_id as reported in StackAuth 1.1 (invalid) and 1.0 (valid)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth

For the association id 1de2e2b0-2fb6-4db6-b90d-d0244ed5d13a, the [StackAuth 1.1 call](http://stackauth.com/1.1/users/1de2e2b0-2fb6-4db6-b90d-d0244ed5d13a/associated) returns an invalid user_id of 73203 for Server Fault whereas the [StackAuth 1.0 call](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/1de2e2b0-2fb6-4db6-b90d-d0244ed5d13a/associated) returns the correct user_id of 18096 for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that association got interrupted by a build.  Cleared and recreated to fix.