# StackAuth 1.1 API reports a site without a site_name

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth

[Calling the StackAuth 1.1 API associated method for a particular user](http://stackauth.com/1.1/users/776bbf5f-921e-4db1-8e30-a0dfb4e2acdb/associated?page=1&pagesize=100) returns one site with no site_name property (the one for which the user_id is 349).  I cannot find a matching account in corresponding StackAuth 1.0 API results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We closed the [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) site today - and I verified against the provided data dump that user 349 matches up.

I strongly suspect this to be a caching issue that will resolve itself.