# API v1.1 users call returns association_id for which the Stack Exchange web site has no profile

Tags: bug, api, associated

For [a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711232/joost), the [`users` API v1.1 call](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1711232) returns an `association_id` that gives a "Page Not Found" error [where the Stack Exchange profile should be](http://stackexchange.com/users/705af49e-38d2-1c16-b05a-f49e35176016), though [their Stack Exchange profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1893844/joost) can be accessed via the "Accounts" link in their profile on another site.  Making the API call against the associated accounts on various Stack Exchange sites yields the same `association_id`.  Is there something wrong with this user's account/association?

***edit*** Here is [another particular user](https://stackapps.com/users/14720/crazy-buddy) for whom the [`users` API v1.1 call](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/users/14720) returns an `association_id` that gives a "Page Not Found" error [where the Stack Exchange profile should be](http://stackexchange.com/users/749e38d2-7c16-105a-f49e-38d2750fce12), though [their Stack Exchange profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1719640/crazy-buddy) can be accessed via the "Accounts" link in their profile on another site

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion how to fix this? I can't find any similarities between me and the other guy mentioned in the post.. That profile seems quite vacant.

Comment: Hi Isaac, I'm leaving this site. And, I think I could add a bounty for this. Please select the good answer so that bounty may get awarded. Bye & Thanks :-)

Comment: Saw this in global-login.js

        `// WARNING: this happens on EVERY SINGLE PAGE 
        // this the core global login function for every user, even the anonymous ones that have no login 
        // the reason this stays sane is because we set this "gauthed" cookie on the first
        // attempt to do global auth, and we don't ever try again FOR THE CURRENT BROWSER SESSION`