# Stackoverflow as an app on Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windows Phone 7?

Tags: discussion, app-request, windows-phone

Do you know of an app for Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windows Phone 7 that let me use stackoverflow.com and hast most (if not all) features of the site itself. Maybe there is one currently in development? I was hoping for a more streamlined user experience on my current and future smartphone.

Comment: if you ask me , I'd say an app should be a limited subset of the functionality of the actual site.  for example:  maybe the app should only show data from threads you are already involved in... and perform like a "check my stack threads" tool.

Answer (score 11):

Not only does [Stacky](http://stacky.codeplex.com) *claim* to support Windows Phone 7, **it actually does!** :) And I am building a WP7 client using it. Here are some early** screen shots:

[image: List of Users]
[image: List of Tags]
[image: Choose a Site]
[image: Home Menu]

** Note that this is very early and none of the UI is final.

Comment: Thanks for the update on this (+1) - I didn't want to sound doubtfully, but you are comparatively quiet regarding further development of your library as well as samples and documentation, so it seems reasonable to advise prospective users to evaluate the state of affairs themselves ;) I've updated my answer accordingly now!

Comment: No worries. I guess I have just been working on other stuff ;)

Comment: *WAHOO!*  I love Stack Exchange and WP7, so this looks **awesome**! nice work +1

Comment: Looks great! Can't wait to try it.

Comment: This looks awesome! Please, let us know when we can try this!

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

Meanwhile Luke [jumped in regarding his upcoming Windows Phone 7 client](https://stackapps.com/questions/1676/stackoverflow-as-an-app-on-windows-mobile-6-5-and-windows-phone-7/1684#1684), so in addition to the options outlined below you might watch his activities to eventually be amongst the first to try it :)

---

I'm not aware of an existing one for either platform yet. If nobody jumps in regarding the *in development* question, you seem to have the following options for the moment:

- Check out George Edisons [StackMobile.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone), a *low-bandwidth version of all StackExchange sites designed specifically for smartphones*. (Notice on the site that a new overhaul is in the works - with new features and a new theme!)
- Simply browse natively, quite a few users seem to be just fine with this, despite several shortcomings.

  - See [Mobile / iPhone Optimized Version of SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/896?tab=votes#tab-top) for a respective discussion - don't get fooled though, that isn't really `status-completed`, see the comments on [Jeffs answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689) for a nice example that he sometimes either doesn't read, doesn't want to listen or simply doesn't get what a mobile-optimized version of a website actually is; to be fair, I should mention that they implemented some improvements regarding the mobile experience, see e.g. Jeffs comment to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/12564#12564).
- Build an app yourself and get praise and recognition from your peers :)

  - Sky Sanders most excellent [Soapi.CS](https://stackapps.com/questions/386/soapi-cs-a-fully-relational-fluent-net-stack-exchange-api-client-library) seems to be best suited for this, he has done quite some work specifically for Silverlight and  Windows Phone 7 - personally I've only tested the former so far though. His library features a couple of important features required for any decent client project already, which are not exactly easy to implement and probably lacking in several others still therefore, e.g. [Caching and Throttling](https://stackapps.com/questions/386/soapi-cs-a-fully-relational-fluent-net-stack-exchange-api-client-library/416#416).
  - [Stacky](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library) from lfoust supports Windows Phone 7 as well, but is indeed lacking Caching and Throttling for example, [as far as I know](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library/634#634).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty slow to the battle... but I love just StackOverflow so i'm working on my own quick & dirty client.  Just to show my profile details and maybe some of the latest questions... Just for me to read when i'm on the road... I'm no Jon Skeet or anything.

Warning, no design work has been done WHATSOEVER!

I'm hosting the source of my personal TFS instance, but when I get close to release, i'm going to open the source up so someone can learn from my mistakes.

I am using the SOAPI api, and it really allows me to create excellent XAML sample data using Visual Studio and databaind to the results of the queries directly.

Awesome stuff!
[Message Box Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lISBj.jpg)
      
[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vldwk.jpg)
[image: Message Box]
[image: Questions List]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** App now on Marketplace - see [Overflow7 - Stack Exchange sites on Windows Phone 7](https://stackapps.com/questions/1942/overflow7-stack-exchange-sites-on-windows-phone-7)

---

Love the look of these apps - Stack Overflow and the Metro UI are a great combination.

Using the excellent Stacky library as a start, here's my latest app - "overflow 7".

There's still more to do - and there always will be - but you can see the app in action at:

[YouTube link](http://bit.ly/overflow7)

[image]

I submitted it to the Marketplace late last night - based on Microsoft's current timing and allowing for one resubmission loop, then I expect the app will be available in about a week.

I've run out of free app submissions - so the price will be 0.99. All money received will encourage me to add more features. If 0.99 is too expensive, then there is a free never-ending full-function trial available :)

I want to get this v1 app through the marketplace first, but once it's accepted then I'll open up a new question asking for feedback, suggestions, ideas, contributions...