# Overflow7 - Stack Exchange sites on Windows Phone 7

Tags: app, silverlight, windows-phone

#### Video of 1.0

On YouTube - http://bit.ly/stackoverflowforwp7

#### About

This is a Stack Overflow app for Windows Phone 7 - it allows you to browse, read and bookmark Stack Exchange sites

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### License and Download

There are two versions of the app available:

[Free link](http://bit.ly/stackoverflowWP7) - full functionality, no time limit - free - available now

[Paid link](http://bit.ly/zuneoverflow7) - if you want to purchase the app for 0.99 then you'll help encourage me to add more features :) Also includes a free never-ending "Trial mode"

#### Platform

Windows Phone 7 - WP7

#### Contact

I created the app - you can contact me via me[at]slodge[dot]com

I'd love to get feedback about what people want

#### Code

App is written in Silverlight-WP7 using hand-crafted MVVM (must start using a library like MVVM Light one day!)

I made use of the excellent [stacky library](http://stacky.codeplex.com)

#### Versions

- 1.0 - first release
- 1.1 - major memory improvements (ListBox and VirtualizingStackPanel)
- 1.2 - a bug fix + major Markdown rendering improvements (links and images)
- 1.3 - addition of UserBadges to some displays
- 1.4 - markdown improvement -

  now rendered

  1.5 - comments included - page orientation fixed to portrait - autoload added to lists - when you scroll to the bottom of the page then the next page loads.

  1.6 - bugfix for more than 10 answers - sorry!

  1.7 - rebuilt with the Jan 2011 tools (needed for cut, copy, paste), also let the app run under the lock screen and added an embedded web browser - makes the whole experience faster :)

  1.8 - glance and go design changes, performance improvements

  1.9 - more 'glance and go' changes - now you can set a site as Home - so if you only care about SuperUser then you'll go straight there when the app starts

  1.10 - some minor adjustments to navigation - especially as 1.9 had a back button problem - sorry - still more to do here!

A mix of 1.9/1.10 for **Overflow 7** and **Overflow 7 Free** are now on the marketplace today (March 9th).

Comment: +1 for the first Windows Phone 7 app available (assuming no others are in the Marketplace submission queue yet ;) - I suggest adding your introduction video link from [your related answer](http://stackapps.com/questions/1676#1938) here as well: if I hadn't submitted an answer there myself I'd probably not noticed it!

Comment: 1.3 is now on the marketplace - much better than 1.0 thanks to virtualizingstackpanel memory use. Just playing now with auto filling lists when you scroll down. Also looking at adding more on badges and more on comments. Thanks for all the great feedback.

Comment: Looks really nice, thanks. Bought, too :) Suggestion: Live Tile for watched Questions (particularly ones I have contributed to)

Comment: @Program.X - the problem with Live Tile is that it requires a server connection - which requires a whole other app - will see if there's any way I can do it using the API and a webservice (e.g. something YQL or Yahoo! pipe-y!)

Comment: +1 so glad to see an app for the WP7 on here! I don't have one myself (yet) but keep up the good work! :)

Comment: beat me to it :) just got my WP7 and downloading it.. will pick up the paid one... r u looking for any dev support as well?

Comment: If you fancy helping to take it to the next level, then YES! Mail me.. me at slodge dot com (but don't expect too quick an answer this week!)

Comment: I'll encourage you.

Comment: could you make this available to all markets? I cannot find it in nl-NL market! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, want to try your app, but I cant find it in marketplace. I am from Czech republic. Is your app submitted world-wide?

Comment: @jumbo If you can't find this app, may be try StackCook. It's on Windows Phone 8.1.